# simple multi-threaded server chat using java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I'm creating a java chat server that handles multi clients I use this simple code for server

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    private int unique_id;
    ArrayList<Clients> cl;


    public Server(int port) {
        try { 
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            cl = new ArrayList<>();
            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error 5");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Server Start");
            while (true){
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Clients t = new Clients(socket); // add it to thread
                    cl.add(t);
                    t.start();
                    System.out.println("Connected " + String.valueOf(cl.size())); // printed ok 
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error 4");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
    public synchronized void SendToAll(String s){ // this function used by client when one of client socket send a message then server send it to all
        System.out.println("Sended is excuted"); // excuted normal each time i send a message from client but not send to all  
        for (int i = 0; i < cl.size(); i++){
            cl.get(i).WriteToSocket(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int port = 5002;
        Server server = new Server(port); // start server
        //server.run(); // start connections wait for it
    }

    class Clients extends Thread { // class extends thread
        public Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream input = null; // read input
        DataOutputStream output = null; // read output
        public int myid = 0; // unique id for each client

        public Clients(Socket soc) {
            socket = soc;
            try {
                input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                myid = ++unique_id;
                System.out.println("Client Start Thread"); // printed ok !
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error 1");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void WriteToSocket(String s) { // used to write a message to this socket
            try {
                output.write(s.getBytes());
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error 2");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() { // run thread function wait for messages from clients 
            while (true){
                try {
                    String s = input.readLine();
                    if (s.contains("quite")) {
                        socket.close();
                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                        cl.remove(this);
                        this.stop();
                    }
                    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                        SendToAll(s);// when message come and not empty it use server function to send them to all clients 
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Error 3");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

everything works fine when clients connect the server accept the connection and the client thread started 
but the problem when I sent a message from the client it didn't received by the server I try my client application in java too with Qt c++ server and it works ?
so what did I do wrong here make the server can't receive the message ?
this my first time in network programming using java 
**Edit** 
I solve the ***NullPointerException*** the problem was that when client log out I didn't remove his socket from the ArrayList solved by making client before close send message contains quite so when I see it i remove his socket from array list
 **Another Quetiosn**
 Here i don't know how this message sent
the System.out.println() that is in the SendToAll function printed to the screen each time client send a message but why the message not send again to all clients ? 
 actually  the main problem is that server can't send the message to all clients in the array list after message comes from one client the **problem not solved stell found** 

Client Code class

```
public class ClientSocket extends Thread {
    public Socket socket = null;
    public DataInputStream input = null;
    public DataOutputStream output = null;
    MainChat chat = null;

    public ClientSocket(String ip, int port,MainChat ch) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip,port);
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            chat = ch;
            this.start();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            try {
                String s = input.readLine();
                if (!s.isEmpty()){
                   chat.WriteToScreen(s.trim());
                }
            }catch (IOException e){

            }
        }
    }
    public void WriteToSocket(String s) throws IOException{
        output.write(s.getBytes());
    }

}
```

Edit 
when i use this code in main the SendToAll function send the message to all clients !! why when i use it from clients class using Thread it not sended to all ?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int port = 5002;
    Server server = new Server(port); // start server
    //server.run(); // start connections wait for it
    while (true) {
        String s = in.next();
        server.SendToAll(s + "\n"); // message sended to all client !!
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a problem and you're catching and ignoring exceptions? First thing to try - `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: i add now in each cath e.printStackTrace(); i didn't get any problem but when i close the client and server is running i got this error

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Server$Clients.run(Server.java:91)

Comment: "The Exception  occurs when you declare a variable but did not create an object " what I do wrong then in which line I and why it occurred when I close the client application ?

Comment: @AndyTurner the problem not solved yes i just solve the problem you sent me it's solution. stell clients can't get messages from server !!

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you

Comment: Can you show the client code? BTW you have a race condition accessing cl from two different threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: @rodolk i add the code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that readLine reads until it finds a line terminator of end of file. This is why it works with other server in QT C++ but not with the Java server.
Please see here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readLine()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()

Please note that readLine in DataInputStream is deprecated. You should use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read a line (with readLine) as indicated in the [DataInputStream link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()).

So, add '\n' to the end of the string sent and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, I am sorry for that it was my fault I forget to add **\n** in sendToAll function so this what cause the problem so no \n the clients can't read the line because I use readLine in DataInputStream 
anyway I try another method to read bytes instead of readLine it's I think it's better especially when you receive UTF-8 char and after that changes from bytes to String